# 'Content-Length' Header affecting parsing of request Gin Gonic

Tags: javascript, go, postman, sveltekit, go-gin

I am making an app where an image is taken by the user then sent to the backend as json with some other keys as ***base64*** data. When I try to send the content from my frontend (sveltekit) it doesn't work and Gin gives me either

```
invalid character 'o' looking for beginning of value
// or
EOF
```

depending on whether I send the Content-Length header with the request.

When I send the same request from postman (which autosets the Content-Length header) it works. I tried implementing the content-length header in my frontend - see below.

*dataurl is a b64 string from canvas.toDataURL()*

```js
const uploadImage = () => {
        // console.log(dataURL);
        let frdurl = dataURL.toString();
        frdurl = frdurl.split(",", 2);
        let tos = frdurl[1];
        console.log(typeof(tos));
        console.log(tos)

        let b = {
                data: tos,
                User: "test2"
            }
        fetch("http://localhost:8080/uploaddaily", {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'cors',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            cors: 'no-cors',
            redirect: 'follow',
            referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
            headers: {
                'Content-Length': JSON.stringify(b).length.toString(), // <-- THIS IS THE MAIN PART
            },
            body: b
        })
        .then(res => {
            return res.json()
        });
    }
```

BACKEND:

```
    var req struct {
        User string `json:"User"`
        Data string `json:"data"`
    }

    if err := c.BindJSON(&req); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "error": err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }

    ef, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(string(req.Data))

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("b64 decode")
        fmt.Print(err)
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "message": "Internal Server Error",
        })
        return
    }

    r := bytes.NewReader(ef)

    file, err := png.Decode(r)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("png decode")
        fmt.Print(err)
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
            "message": "Internal Server Error",
        })
        return
    }
```

Comment: But it doesn't work without the content-length header - I tested for that.

Comment: Added the part that matters

Comment: The server expects a JSON request body. Set the content type header to application/json.  Set the body to JSON.stringify(b).  Do not set the content length header.